# Connecting a usb external drive in NFS to a different server

Tags: linux, networking, backup, nfs, usb

I have two unix CentOS servers in the same farm. One of them has an usb HD connected. I would like to access the same usb HD from the second server (I want to be able to write directly to that HD). Can someone guide me through the steps I need to perform that operation?

Comment: No, this is fairly basic to achieve and this site is for professional sysadmins. It's not a support site for people who can't be bothered doing even the most basic of self research. Please have a look at our [faq].

Comment: Is this more suited for the main SO? I actually did more than a basic research, but found out I'm missing some experience a professional sysadmin has, and should ask for guidance, thought this was the right place.

Comment: No, SO is for programmers - Please read their FAQ too. Same for an [SE] site. Then you'll know what we're here for and more specifically what we're not. We're here for Professional SysAdmins, not as a single point for people to nag them. As for research did you do anything as complex as Googling "setup nfs"?

Comment: I actually read through a couple of the links google pointed out to and had a hard time making sure the two servers can connect, and understand if the fact that it's a usb drive should make this different. Thanks for your time, I will look for a community that includes professional sysadmins that are willing to help programmers with issues they think are staggeringly basic.

Comment: @Noam: It won't make a difference that it is a USB device. Just mount it and share it through NFS as any other local directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. mount the drive locally
2. export the drive via nfs
3. on the second server mount the drive over nfs and/or add it to fstab

each of these steps is in man or easily googleable